# Searching for "markup" in the Help Center should return the page on Markdown

Tags: feature-request, search, markdown, help-center

Just tried searching help with the keyword "markup" and it returned 0 results. What?

[image]

I think search should suggest that perhaps I meant "markdown" instead.

All the articles about Markdown should have a keyword [markup](/questions/tagged/markup) added so they would still appear in search. I think this should be possible to do right now, as it doesn't involve any coding (only use the site's help page editing interface) without any unforeseen trouble.

Comment: Yes, markup is a very different thing to markdown.

Comment: Then there should be a corresponding help section explaining that and also saying "Did you mean ‘markdown’?" and linking to the relevant results.

Comment: Markup is a category of languages.  Markdown is one specific language that happens to be in that category.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/243335/what-is-the-difference-between-markup-and-markdown but it is deleted for fair reasons :D

Comment: @user1306322 There are *many* more *much* more important pieces of information that needs to be provided to users in the help center.  That's just not a frequent enough question that is important enough to merit being in the help center.  It's not like you can't easily find the answer to that problem, it's just that you need to go outside the SO help center to find it (like, say, just googling each term).

Comment: can we just agree that this may be considered a common mistake for users not very familiar with everything related to SE that "markdown" and "markup" are the same thing and show the "markdown"'s results for both queries? I mean I've been using SE for a long time and I only just now found out about this.

Comment: As it is now, it looks like a rude move, like saying "Haha, puny human! You don't even know how the thing you're looking for is called correctly. Of course we won't help you!" just not cool

Comment: I'm with you on making search more helpful, but... this is hardly a bug. What you're asking for is predictive search/autocorrections, which I *think* are on our list somewhere, but I'm not sure what work's involved there off the top of my head. You're also reading an awful lot into "I searched for the wrong thing and came up with 0 results".

Comment: It's not like I typed "squiggly brackety thing symbols". I did use a pretty common term.

Comment: @user1306322 The help center isn't designed to be a place for every user to find everything they ever would want to know.  If it did, people would rarely ever read any of it, and wouldn't be able to find the most important information.  The help center is a glorified FAQ.  This question is simply *not* a frequently asked question, or a common problem.  In fact this is the first time I've ever seen someone asking about it.

Comment: @Servy Everything happens for the first time sometime. I saw this problem, I thought this would be a piece of cake to implement (being a programmer) and so I decided to ask about it. I usually do these things, so stay tuned if you share my outlook ;)

Comment: @user1306322 Unless we literally go `if(searchStr == "markup") doSearch("markdown")`, it's a wee bit more involved. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear that is exactly the kind of quick fix I expected. And I don't really see any reason to do anything more complicated. This automatically substitutes the wrong word to the right one, so the user knows what happened, and doesn't require any additional coding like some info message "You entered a wrong word and we changed it for you". This is self-explanatory enough.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4qEmR.gif

Comment: Well, I'm going with this. Let others who do have time explain to me and everybody else why this is wrong.

Comment: The articles about Markdown should at some point contain the keyword "markup". (For obvious reasons.) It's a much easier fix than hacking in a specific edge case.

Comment: I wholly agree with Eric and change my request to that!

Comment: The thing is Markdown. If you start throwing about "markup" all over the place you're going to have users call reputation EXP, and make them think accounts with 3,000+ reputation are moderators

Comment: @random Not a valid analogy. Markdown is a type of [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), while reputation is not a type of XP. Including the word "markup" somewhere in the page that *describes our markup language* does not seem unreasonable.

Comment: @user1306322 You ask what's wrong with the proposed quick-fix. The answer is: It is a quick-fix, and the "bug" it fixes is far from being critical. Only critical bugs get quick-fixes, but even there it's supposed that the fix will be made better. Why is it a quick-fix? It has no conception, it's not thought out, difficult to document, it's behaviour is actually unpredictable (in 1 month / 1 new developer, you have no clue why "markup" returns something, nor why there're 2 strange lines in your code). This is just a short and incomplete summary of the cons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a valid point there: a user searching for "markup" in Help Center should be directed to [the formatting page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and it's not happening.

My suggestion is to include the word "markup" in the first paragraph of that page:

> When posting on Meta Stack Exchange, you can use the visual editor (for questions and answers, but not comments), **[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)**, and [some **HTML**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). Markdown is a human-readable markup language; if you're new to it, you may want to [visit the official Markdown syntax reference page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that "markup" needs to be explicitly written somewhere or searchable. On the other hand, I agree that the Help post [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) could appear in the Help categories *Asking* and *Answering* as well as in *Our model*, where it is now, since it's not really intuitive to look for it there.

As well, you get link to the markdown help directly next to the textarea when you're typing (see below), which brings you to a very detailed markdown manual.

> [image]

Comment: Your red looks sick. ;)

Comment: It's pure `0xff0000` with roughly `0.5` opacity, I prefer it this way since you can still see the text below ;)

Comment: lol, fair enough. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Next taime, I wil doo bettzr I promiz. I wil pute tze redz on tze botome lajr and suprpozicion tze tekst ovr id, so tzat itz reeeli redz :D